# How can scrape "Accessibility" part of Chrome Developer Tools? (Python)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-crawler, google-chrome-devtools, screen-scraping

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmPJl.png)

(Please check out the image description above)

Hello, I am scraping some websites with Python.

It is an active web so I failed to scrape some contents with the libraries, BeautifulSoup and requests.

But I've checked the contents that I want to scrape are included in the "Accessibility" part.

So if I ever scrape this part, I can obtain the contents without further parsing efforts.

Any idea?

Thank you.

I am checking the Chrome Developer Tools guidelines etc,

but can not find a proper solution.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

as you describe it, I assume the page is not fully hydrated on load

to execute the javascript on the page you can use [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/index.html) or it's alternatives, which will spawn a browser, which you can query for elements.